# Printable templates for Custom Modules

Tags: zoho

I have a requirement to setup customized printable for few Custom Modules to let the record owner print  the details of the currently opened record, similar to Invoice Template or Sales Order Template.

**Use Case:**

- Record Owner opens a record from Custom Module
- A custom button Print Record will appear when a record is opened
- On clicking the Print Record button, a PDF document with data of the opened record must be generated  based on a template (similar to Invoice template) and either download the generated PDF record owner's local drive or send the generated PDF to a specific email address

Is there a way to set up Invoice Templates for Custom modules? It can be achieved with Mail Merge but I need the outcome as a PDF document and with Mail Merge doing that would require several clicks. I need the PDF to be generated on a single button click.

Also, can the aforementioned use case be automated? Automatically generate a PDF based on a template periodically and send it by email without the user having to navigate the record and print the PDF manually?

I would appreciate any guidance on this use case.